# Get coordinates of nodes in a polyline using ogr2ogr

Tags: qgis, ogr, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to figure out how to extract coordinates of first and last node of a ESRI shape polyline using ogr2ogr.

In QGIS I use `xat(n)` and `yat(n)`, so what I'm looking for is the same result using ogr2ogr in the terminal.

The reason I want this is to first calculate the angle between the points (in QGIS I use `(atan((xat(0)-xat(1))/(yat(0)-yat(1)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(0)-yat(1)) < 0) + (((xat(0)-xat(1)) < 0 AND (yat(0) - yat(1)) >0)*2)))` and then store these values in an attribute column and turn the line object into a point object.

I'd like to do this for each feature in the shapefile.

Comment: I don't think ogr2ogr can do this - its meant for converting shapefiles to GML, or other format conversions, or projection transformations. You could maybe use `ogrinfo` to dump the attributes and geometry and then parse that with another script to create the output you need, but you might as well write a script in python using the shapely or gdal python packages rather than mess with shell scripts...

Comment: I solved it! See below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking in to PostGIS I found that `ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(geometry))` is basically the same as QGIS `xat(0)`.

```
ogrinfo file.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE file SET angle = (atan((ST_X(ST_StartPoint(geometry))-ST_X(ST_EndPoint(geometry)))/(ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(geometry))-ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(geometry))))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(geometry))-ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(geometry))) < 0) + (((ST_X(ST_StartPoint(geometry))-ST_X(ST_EndPoint(geometry))) < 0 AND (ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(geometry)) - ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(geometry))) >0)*2)))"
```

Comment: please mark it as answer :)

Comment: Now you can \o/